# How to have value as an array in Javascript Map?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, multidimensional-array, hashmap

I need to have a map which has keys and the corresponding values as an array, How do I do that?

```
[
{
"language": "english",    
"movie_name": "die-hard",
"movie_size": 89
},{
"language": "english",
"movie_name": "inception",
"movie_size": 40
},{
"language": "english",
"movie_name": "Lionking",
"movie_size": 50
},{
"language": "spanish",
"movie_name": "L'amour",
"movie_size": 10
},
{
"language": "spanish",
"movie_name": "L'amour",
"movie_size": 65
},{
"language": "english",
"movie_name": "inception",
"movie_size": 70
},{
"language": "english",
"movie_name": "die-hard",
"movie_size": 62
}
]
```

The above is my data structure and with my code below I am able to form a map which prints the number of movies per language.

And I have a code [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xdhun1m3/) which currently prints the following to the console

```
 Map{
'english' => Map {'die-hard' => 2, 'inception' => 2, 'Lionking' => 1},
'spanish' => Map {'L'amour' => 2} }
```

But I want to calculate percentile based on the movie size, for which I need all the movie_size for a particular movie_name based on the language. I am not sure how this could be achieved.

Comment: _map which has keys and the corresponding values as an array_ so an object with properties/keys and their values being arrays?

Comment: What is the output you are expecting?

Comment: Please click the `<>` and provide the code you have with example of expected output in a [mcve]

Comment: @mplungjan Code at jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/xdhun1m3/ , The above code works and prints the above output.

Comment: @Mamun I am expecting to calculate percentile of the movie size. For which i need all the values corresponding to a movie_name code at jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xdhun1m3/  Output i am expecting is as i will be calling a percentile method on the array which contains moviesize values or a particular movie name something like die-hard => 89 (assuming 89 is the output from the percentile function)

Comment: @George Yes but at the end of my operation i would like to have a percentile for each movie based on the movie size for percentile calculation i am using the stats-percentile library, But it needs a array of data which i am not able to provide from the above json.

Answer (score 0):

Set the value as array `[]` and `.push` to add items to it:

```js
array = [ { "language": "english", "movie_name": "die-hard-4k"   , "movie_size": 89 }, 
          { "language": "english", "movie_name": "inception-1080", "movie_size": 40 },
          { "language": "english", "movie_name": "Lionking-4k"   , "movie_size": 50 },
          { "language": "spanish", "movie_name": "L'amour-1080"  , "movie_size": 10 },
          { "language": "spanish", "movie_name": "L'amour-4k"    , "movie_size": 65 },
          { "language": "english", "movie_name": "inception-4k"  , "movie_size": 70 },
          { "language": "english", "movie_name": "die-hard-1080" , "movie_size": 62 } ]

result = {}
for (item of array) {
  language = result[item.language] || (result[item.language] = {})
  movie_name = item.movie_name.replace(/-[^-]*$/, '')
  movie_size = language[movie_name] || (language[movie_name] = [])
  movie_size.push(item.movie_size)
}

console.log(result)
```

Comment: The above works like a charm and does the need, This could be a ideal solution for anyone handling nested json and want to map based on certain attributes.